# TrixBox Message Waiting Indicator in Device and User Mode

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, trixbox

My trixbox installation supports hot-desking, so that users can take any desk and log into the phone. To do this, I placed FreePBX into Device-and-User mode, which allows the devices (phones) and users to be created and maintained seperately. In this configuration, a device can either have a fixed user, or it can be dynamically assigned to whichever user logs in. It all works beautifully!

One problem - MWI (message waiting indicators) no longer work when a user has voicemail. I use Cisco 7900 phones and normally the red lamp under the handset lights up when there's a voicemail. However, this doesn;t seem to work in device-and-user mode. What a bummer!

Has anyone got any ideas for getting my MWI back?

Comment: No idea on the stupid red light, but an alternative suggestion: Configure trixbox to email the users their voicemail messages instead?  This has to be the single most popular feature of our VOIP deployment :-)

Comment: @voretag7 - indeed, that is the solution I am currently using (so +1). BUT, it means I have to automatically delete the voicemail after it has been sent, to keep the disks clean. It would be _really_ useful if, when a user logs into their phone, 'pop!' the voicemail light comes on if they have messages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know have you this already resolved, but i may suggest to check your devices mailbox option on the FreePBX GUI and must be like this "device-number@device". Whenever agent logged in with their ampuser extension the system made a link from directory device-number@device  to ampuser@default voicemail directory and link the messages from that device to specific ampuser that has logged in on that device.